# How to Ban / Unban IP for failed login attempts

Tags: java, jsp

I want to IP Ban a user if he fails to login 5 times at my website. How do I get someone's IP in Java and then ban it from my site?

Currently, my login servlet looks like this. I know the counting system should be implemented differently and I will get working on that later. For now, I just want to test out IP bans.

```
if(user.isValid())
            {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user);

                response.sendRedirect("Unit_Info.jsp");
            }else{
                x=x+1;
                System.out.println("Failed Login " + x + "\n");

                if(x==5)
                    response.sendRedirect("http://google.com"); //IP BAN HIM
                else
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); 
            }
```

EDIT: Now that I think about it more, what happens if someone is using a proxy and constantly changing IPs when trying out username/passwords. Is there a sure way to ban the guy, whether he is using a proxy or not?

Comment: For proxy (if it's not totally anonymous) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 1):

You could use fail2ban to achieve the same. Here is the [resource](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Else you can have a bit in the db which sets once it crosses the number of attempts parameter. You can put those IP addresses in the blocked list of the server.

Comment: Yeah, currently in my DB I have an accounts table, a failed attempts table, and a banned IP table. Would be there be anything else I need for this login process?

Comment: That is fine enough for the process. You can achieve it by using the same resources. But I tell you blocking should be temporary. If you permanently block it the main users might be affected.

Comment: What's a good system for a temporary ban? I was thinking that in situations where the main users get banned, they can just call up the db administrators to unban them.

Comment: One option might be that or add a time-stamp with your blocked IP and delete it after some time like 1 day, 2 day or time of your privilege.